# typescript problem with adding array of objects to new array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to show my data(recipes) on frontend. When I console.log(data) that I get from server I have object with property of 'msg' that contains array of objects..
I can access that array with `data['msg' as keyof typeof data])`
So when I console.log that I get an array of objects[logging msg property of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cirNM.png)
Now my problem is when I try to assign that array to `this.recipe` array.
When I try `this.recipe = data['msg' as keyof typeof data]` I get an error:

> Type 'Function' is missing the following properties from type 'Recipe[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 27 more.

But when I try use push() I get

> Type 'Function' is missing the following properties from type 'Recipe': description, ingredients

I'm relatively new to Angular and I'm lost.
If you need some other chunks of my code let me now, I didn't want to copy paste lot of it, because I'm not sure where problem is and what would be helpful.I've put here the file where I get the problem.

Code where I get problem:

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  public recipes: Recipe[];
  constructor(private _recipeService: RecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.readRecipes();
  }
  readRecipes() {
    this._recipeService.readRecipes().subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this.recipes = data['msg' as keyof typeof data];
      }
      ,
      error: (error) => console.log(error),
      complete: () => console.info('complete')

    }

    )
  }

}
```

my recipe.service.ts file:

```
export class RecipeService {
  private baseUri: string = "http://localhost:8080";
  private headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  createRecipe(recipe: Recipe) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUri + '/create', recipe, { headers: this.headers });
  }

  readRecipes() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUri + '/read', { headers: this.headers });
  }

  updateRecipe(recipe: Recipe) {
    return this.http.put(this.baseUri + '/update', recipe, { headers: this.headers });
  }

  deleteRecipe(id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.baseUri + '/delete/' + id, { headers: this.headers });
  }
}
```

backend part of code for read route:

```
router.get('/read', (req, res, next) => {
Recipe.find({}, (err, recipes) => {
    if (err)
        res.status(500).json({
            errmsg: err
        });
    res.status(200).json({
        msg: recipes
    });

});
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by attaching the source code and JSON data as snippets instead of images. Thanks.

Comment: Please try to upload the code to stackblitz

Comment: I edited my first post, I hope it's more readable now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this is to use the `async` pipe in Angular:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ul *ngIf="(employees$ | async).length">
      <li *ngFor="let employee of employees$ | async">{{employee.name}}</li>
    </ul>  
  `
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit { 
  employees$: Observable<Employee[]>;
 
  constructor(private service: MyService) {}
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.employees$ = this.service.getEmployees$();
  }
}
```

Here's a fork of your Stackblitz that shows the list of recipes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r97jph?file=src/app/components/list/list.component.ts

Comment: I tried it, but I get similar problem again.. Now I get "Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Recipe[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more."

Comment: @PezerAFC please provide a Stackblitz link and I'd be happy to assist you there.

Comment: Thanks.. I never used Stackblitz before, so I hope I done it okay...
Here is link of frontend part: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y9kzl9
Backend: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-padpgx

Answer (score 0):

Just to write here that I found solution.

On the backend I send response as `res.JSON({msg:recipes})` and I couldn't access to the `msg` object, but when I changed the code to `res.JSON(recipes)` with only parentheses `()`  I was able to get the array. Then with a new `data` variable, I accessed the response array with `this.recipes=data`.